# Task not serializable about aggegateByKey

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Environment: spark 1.60. i use scala.
i can compile the program by sbt, but when i commit the program, it came across the error.
My full error is as followed:

```
238 17/01/21 18:32:24 INFO net.NetworkTopology: Adding a new node: /YH11070029/10.39.0.213:50010
17/01/21 18:32:24 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block  manager 10.39.0.44:41961 with 2.7 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(349, 10.39.0.44, 41961)
17/01/21 18:32:24 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.39.2.178:48591 with 2.7 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(518, 10.39.2.178,  48591)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not     serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$combineByKeyWithClassTag$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$combineByKeyWithClassTag$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.combineByKeyWithClassTag(PairRDDFunctions.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$aggregateByKey$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$aggregateByKey$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.aggregateByKey(PairRDDFunctions.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$aggregateByKey$3.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$aggregateByKey$3.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.aggregateByKey(PairRDDFunctions.scala:205)
    at com.sina.adalgo.feature.ETL$$anonfun$13.apply(ETL.scala:190)
    at com.sina.adalgo.feature.ETL$$anonfun$13.apply(ETL.scala:102)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
```

The purpose of code is to statistic categorical features' frequentencies. Main code is as followed:

```
object ETL extends Serializable {
           ... ...


val cateList = featureData.map{v =>
    case (psid: String, label: String, cate_features: ParArray[String], media_features: String) =>
        val pair_feature = cate_features.zipWithIndex.map(x => (x._2, x._1))
        pair_feature
}.flatMap(_.toList)

def seqop(m: HashMap[String, Int] , s: String) : HashMap[String, Int]={
    var x = m.getOrElse(s, 0)
    x += 1
    m += s -> x
    m   
}   

def combop(m: HashMap[String, Int], n: HashMap[String, Int]) : HashMap[String, Int]={
    for (k <- n) {
        var x = m.getOrElse(k._1, 0)
        x += k._2
        m += k._1 -> x
    }   
    m   
}   

val hash = HashMap[String, Int]()
val feaFreq = cateList.aggregateByKey(hash)(seqop, combop)// (i, HashMap[String, Int]) i corresponded with categorical feature
```

The object have inheritated Serializable.
why? can u help me?

Comment: could you add the code? No way to see the cause of the problem with only the exception.

Comment: "Task not serializable". Detect if your own code has objects that are not serializable.

Comment: the code is showed. i have checked object is serializable.

Answer (score 0):

To me, this problem typically happens in Spark when we use a closure as aggregation function that un-intentially closes over some unwanted objects and/or sometimes simply a function that is inside the main class of our spark driver code.

I suspect this *might* be the case here since your stacktrace involves `org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner` as top level culprit.

This is problematic because in such case, when Spark tries to forward that function to the workers so they can do the actual aggregation, it ends-up serializing much more than you actually intended: the function itelf plus its surrounding class.

See also [this post by Erik Erlandson](http://erikerlandson.github.io/blog/2015/03/31/hygienic-closures-for-scala-function-serialization/) where some border cases of serialisation of closure are well explained as well as [Spark 1.6 notes on closures](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-a-nameclosureslinka).

A quick fix is probably to move the definition of the function you use in the `aggregateByKey` to a separate object, completely independant from the rest of the code.

Comment: tks. i have a try to move the definition of the function you use in the aggregateByKey to a separate object, and it didn't work. My code is posted, and i doubt there is something wrong about hash(HashMap[String, Int])

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and the code. Try to move the `seqop` and `combop` in a separate object, without anything else in that object and outside of `ETL`. I think what's happening here is the whole `ETL` object gets pulled into the serialisation, and since it contains `cateList` and `feaFreq`, which are RDD's, the serialisation fails.